# AJAX Response should update all records in while loop results

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have scratched my head but I could not get the desired result.
in a while loop, all comments are being fetched. each comment has a button with font awesome star sign to make this comment favorite.
I want to show the total number of favorite comments by the logged in user on mouseover on any comment's star button. (So that user may know how many comments i have favorite until now.

I am using jQuery AJAX method to update the records for favorite comments.
Everything is perfectly working fine, favorite comment is being updated in mysql records, and AJAX response is working good.

My actual problem is:
AJAX response is working only for the clicked button.
But I want Two things instead

1. When a favorite button is clicked on any comment, that button should be toggled into favorited one (empty star will be turned into full star) only for this comment which one is clicked to be favorite
2. The Total number of favorite comment by this user should be shown in the title text of each comment's favorite button on mouse hover. So a user can easily see how many comments i have favorited. (After refreshing the page, its showing the results nicely. but it should work without reloading the page, with the help of AJAX response)

I want to show the the total number of favorite comments by logged in user in the title of the button and update them on click event. I am giving the code below so you could easily understand what i want to do

Output Area Code

```
<?php
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `comments`");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
    ?>
    Comments: <?php echo $row['usercom']; ?><br>
    <?php
    $query1 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `favcoms` where fcom_id='" . $row['cid'] . "' and sessionid='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
    $query2 = mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `favcoms` where sessionid='" . $_SESSION['id'] . "'");
    ?>
    <span class="show_like<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>">
        <?php if (mysqli_num_rows($query1) > 0) { ?>
            <button value="<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>" class="unfavcom"><i title="Remove from Favorite? - (<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($query2); ?>/20)" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <button value="<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>" class="favcom"><i title="Favorite Comment - (<?php echo mysqli_num_rows($query2); ?>/20)" class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button>
         <?php } ?>
     </span>
     <?php
}
?>
```

AJAX part here

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).on('click', '.favcom', function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "like.php",
            data: {
                id: id,
                like: 1,
            },
            success: function() {
                showLike(id);
            }
        });
    });

    $(document).on('click', '.unfavcom', function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "like.php",
            data: {
                id: id,
                like: 1,
            },
            success: function() {
                showLike(id);
            }
        });
    });

});

function showLike(id) {
        $.ajax({
            url: 'show_like.php',
            type: 'POST',
            async: false,
            data:{
                id: id,
                showlike: 1
            },
            success: function(response){
                $('.show_like'+id).html(response);

            }
        });
    }
```

and show_like.php here

```
<?php
session_start();
include('conn.php');

if (isset($_POST['showlike'])) {
    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query3=mysqli_query($conn, "select * from `favcoms` where fcom_id='".$id."' and sessionid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $query4 = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `favcoms` where sessionid='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
    $numFavs = mysqli_num_rows($query4);
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query3) > 0) {
        echo '<button class="mycomoptions unfavcom" value="'.$id.'"><font color="#00CC00"><i title="Remove from Favorite? - ('.$numFavs.'/20)" class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i></font></button>';
    } else {
        echo '<button class="mycomoptions favcom" value="'.$id.'"><font color="#00CC00"><i title="Remove from Favorite? - ('.$numFavs.'/20)" class="fa fa-star-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></font></button>' ;
    }   
}   
?>
```

like.php here

```
<?php
include ('conn.php');
session_start();

if (isset($_POST['like'])) {        

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select * from `favcoms` where fcom_id='$id' and sessionid='".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die(mysqli_error());

    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        mysqli_query($conn,"delete from `favcoms` where sessionid='".$_SESSION['id']."' and fcom_id='$id'");
    } else {
        mysqli_query($conn,"insert into `favcoms` (sessionid,fcom_id) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id')");
    }
}       
?>
```

When user favorite any comment, the total number of favorite comments should be increased for every comment but it is updating that number only for that one comment which was favorite by the user (in AJAX Response). After refreshing the page, total number of favorite comments shows fine for each comment.

the clicked button class will be changed, or it should toggle on each click between empty star and colored star. so the font awesome star class will be changed only for clicked button, but the total favorite comments by the user should be updated for all comments.

Hope I have explained well. if you need further explanation, please ask me in comments.

P.S = I am using PDO method in configuration connection file

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks. You should use parameterised queries and prepared statements to help prevent attackers from compromising your database by using malicious input values. http://bobby-tables.com gives an explanation of the risks, as well as some examples of how to write your queries safely using PHP / mysqli. **Never** insert unsanitised data directly into your SQL.

Comment: I agree, look into using [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) to avoid issues with SQL injection

Comment: @ADyson Sir, i will change the code for sure, but here i actually wanted to get the solution with AJAX :/

Comment: need to see the html you're inserting in to. Where is the "total number of favorite comments" code?

Comment: @TimMorton in the `show_like.php` page `$numFavs = mysqli_num_rows($query4);`

Comment: @TimMorton I read your name as Tim Horton, now I really want a coffee and donut.

Comment: Well I see nobody has answered the question while I was on the road. So if I understand correctly, the total starred shows correctly on page load, but after Ajax, only the selected row updates. That’s exactly what your code is telling it to do. There’s nothing that instructs existing rows to update after the Ajax call. If you can wait for an answer, I’ll try to write one up ASAP, but I’m on Thanksgiving break...

Comment: @TimMorton Yes, exactly. on page load, total starred shows correctly. but after AJAX only selected row updates but not the entire loop record. I am still waiting for an answer.

Comment: I started to write up an answer that refactored your code, and found that it was turning into a complete rewrite.  That's not my intention...  What's stopping you from seeing the solution is your usage of `$('.show_like'+id).html(response);`  This is only updating the one button's html.  And therein is the problem.  Your AJAX should be returning JSON for your javascript to manipulate.  If you had a `span class="total_faves"></span>` you could then take the server's response and do something like `$('.total_faves').text(response.total)`.  I'll try to write up something, but my time is limited.

Comment: So, the idea is that you want to mark a comment as favorite, and then refresh the favorite count for every comment?

Comment: @Piyin Exactly, but i want the refresh count for every comment without refreshing the page. Also, i want to toggle the font awesome and the button's title text on click event. before we do anything, let me clear it should work for each click even i click 10 comments without refreshing the page, it should increase or decrease the total favorite count for every comment. Hope you got it

Answer (score 1):

This is going to be way more than you asked for, but it seems like a great opportunity to share some knowledge that I hope will be useful.

I had trouble finding your "total number of comments" code because there should be as much separation of logic and presentation as you can.  So I try not to switch in and out of php unless I'm dropping in values.  This leads to an approach to AJAX that has the server returning JSON instead of HTML.  You're asking the server to do some business logic and then tell you results; not how to format your page.

> Caveat one:  I don't work with mysqli; I use my own data abstraction classes so I don't have to deal with the quirks of PDO vs mysqli vs ODBC etc.  So, my code might not show the best use of mysqli.
>
> Caveat two: This is not tested in a browser, so there could be mistakes.  This is intended to show concepts, not be copy and paste code.

### Connection

```
<?php
/**
 * conn.php
 */

// Create connection
$db = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($db->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $db->connect_error);
}
```

### Initial Page

```
<?php
require ('conn.php');

// get user's total number of likes
$query = "SELECT COUNT(sessionid) AS total_faves FROM favcoms WHERE sessionid=?";
$result = $db->prepare($query);
$result->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['id']);
$result->execute();

$total = '';
if($row=$result->fetch_object()) {
    $total = $row->total_faves;
} else {
    // do something on failure
}

// now get all comments with optional sessionid if it has been favorited. coalesce turns null into '' 
$query = 
    "SELECT DISTINCT c.cid, c.usercom, coalesce(f.sessionid, '') " . 
    "FROM comments AS c " . 
    "LEFT JOIN favcoms AS f ON c.cid=f.fcom_id AND sessionid=? ";

$comment = $db->prepare($query);
$comment->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['id']);
$comment->execute();

?>
```

-- snip --

The HTML portion:

```
<input type="hidden" id="total-faves" value="<?= $total ?>" />

<?php while($row = $comment->fetch_object()): ?>

    <div id="comment-row-<?= $row->cid ?>" class="commentRow">
        Comments: <?= $row->usercom ?>
        <button id="button-<?= $row->cid ?>" 
                val="<?= $row->cid ?>" 
                class="comment-button <?php $row->sessionid ? 'favcom' : 'unfavcom' ?>">
            <i title="Favorite Comment - (<?= $total ?>/20)"
               class="fa fa-star<?php $row->sessionid ? '' : '-o' ?>" 
               aria-hidden="true">
            </i>
        </button> 
    </div>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

If the comment is a favorite, then the icon class will be `fa fa-star`, otherwise, it will just be `fa fa-star-o`.  Javascript will do some magic later...

Now, since your call to `like.php` effectively toggles favorites (adding or deleting in database), just use that to return the results:

### like.php

```
<?php
/**
 * like.php
 */

header('Content-Type: application/json');  // <--- Don't miss this!

require ('conn.php');

if (isset($_POST['id'])) {        

    $id = $_POST['id'];
    $query = "select * from `favcoms` where fcom_id=? and sessionid=?";

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id,$_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute(); // should check if this succeeds.

    // if there is a result, delete it.  if not, add it.
    if ($stmt->fetch_object()) {
        $query = "delete from `favcoms` where fcom_id=? and sessionid=?";
        $status = 'not liked';
    } else {
        $query = "insert into `favcoms` (fcom_id,sessionid) values (?,?)";
        $status = 'liked';
    }

    $stmt = $db->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bind_param("s", $id, $_SESSION['id']);
    $stmt->execute();

    // now find total number of faves and return value
    $query = "SELECT COUNT(sessionid) AS total_faves FROM favcoms";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    $total = '';
    if($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        $total = $row->total_faves;
    }

    echo json_encode(array(
        'result' => 'success',
        'total' => $total,
        'status' => $status
        ));
} else {

echo json_encode(array(
    'result' => 'fail'
    ));    
}
```

### Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    // dynamically generated buttons must reference a parent element
    $(document).on('click', '.comment-button', function() {
        var id=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "like.php",
            data: {
                id: id,
            },
            success: function(data) {

                var total = data.total;
                $('#total-faves').val(total);
                toggleButton(id,data);
                updateTitles();
            }
        });
    });

    // initialize titles here. It could be done in PHP output, but javascript needs to do it later anyway...
    updateTitles();


});


function toggleButton(id,data) {

    var status = data.status;
    var button = $('#button-'+id);
    var icon = button.children('i').eq(0);

    if(status=='liked') {
        button.removeClass('unfavcom').addClass('favcom');
        icon.removeClass('fa fa-star-o').addClass('fa fa-star');
    } else {
        button.removeClass('favcom').addClass('unfavcom');
        icon.removeClass('fa fa-star').addClass('fa fa-star-o');
    }
}

function updateTitles() {

    var total = $('#total-faves').val();
    $('.fa fa-star').prop('title',"Favorite Comment - ("+ data.total +"/20)");
    $('.fa fa-star-o').prop('title',"Remove from Favorite? - ("+ data.total +"/20)");
}
```

The answer to your question is in the function just above-- but to get there I needed to change the AJAX to use JSON instead of HTML.  Then, you can see all the magic available to you through jquery.  All you need to know is which rows are favorited, and you can set the titles, classes, etc with jquery.

-- edit --
I just noticed that I didn't check the AJAX data for success or failure.  You can always check that to give info to the user.  I just forgot to.

Comment: Nicely done - using proper mysli_* functions.  Excellent answer.

Comment: I am getting an error `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method PDOStatement::bind_param() in D:\Website Project\Test\home.php:35 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\Website Project\Test\home.php on line 35` **where line number 35 is** `$result->bind_param("s", $_SESSION['id']);` **I also tried** `$query = "SELECT COUNT(sessionid) AS total_faves FROM favcoms WHERE sessionid=:l_id";` **and** `$result->bind_param(":userid", $_SESSION['id']);`

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO?  My answer used mysqli since that's what you were using.

Comment: I am using mysqli

Comment: Your error says PDOStatement.  That seems a little strange if you're using mysqli.  As I noted, I don't use mysqli, so there could be errors in my code.  As I was looking at the PHP examples, I noticed that there is a potential error in `$stmt->bind_param("s", $id, $_SESSION['id']);` not having two Type specification chars.  But I have no idea what would give you a PDO error in mysqli.

Comment: Gosh, I am sorry, I just checked i am using pdo in connection `$db = new PDO(DB_DRIVER . ':host=' . DB_SERVER . ';dbname=' . DB_DATABASE, DB_SERVER_USERNAME, DB_SERVER_PASSWORD, $dboptions);` 
What changes are required in the code above...

Comment: Well, that would explain it.  `bind_param()` is a `mysqli` method, not a `pdo` method.  That's why it squawked about an undefined method: PDO doesn't have it.

Comment: PDO is (IMO) much better:  `$pdo->prepare($sql)->execute([$values]);` or, as my answer would use it, something like `$db->prepare($query)->execute(array($id, $_SESSION['id']));` (once again, consult the docs because I don't use mysql PDO)

Comment: now its giving another error `Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method mysqli_stmt::fetch_object() in D:\like\home.php:39 Stack trace: #0 {main} thrown in D:\like\home.php on line 39` Where line # 39 is `if($row=$result->fetch_object()) {`

Comment: Decide which one you're going to use, PDO or mysqli. If you connect with PDO, then mysqli commands won't work.

Comment: as already i am using PDO, can you edit your code according to PDO method? instead of bind_param i think we can use bindValue.

Comment: My answer is to describe the concept, not to provide a cut and paste answer. I don't normally work with either PDO nor mysqli, so I have to do the same research you need to do.  At this point, it would be easier for you to work your way around the errors than for me to write the code for you.  There's only two things for you to figure out when moving from mysqli to pdo:  how do you bind (normally, just pass values via array in `execute`) and how do you retrieve values.  I don't want to deprive you of the joy of figuring it out for yourself.  It's a skill that has to be practised to learn :)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's necessary for you to go to the server and bring back the count every time the user makes a change, when you can actually just add or subtract one from everyone in case a comment is liked or disliked, respectively. So what you can do is give some other class to the buttons (to both of them, the `favcom` and the `unfavcom`, so you can access the first of them in a simple way), like this:

```
<button value="<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>" class="unfavcom favbutton"><!-- --></button>
<!-- -->
<button value="<?php echo $row['cid']; ?>" class="favcom favbutton"><!-- --></button>
```

Then, you could create a function to alter the titles after the user likes/unlikes a comment:

```
function updateCounts(delta){
    var newCount = (
        Number(
            $('.favbutton i:first') // Grabs the first button
            .attr('title') // Grabs its title (i.e. Favorite Comment - 10/20)
            .split('- ')[1] // Splits the string by the dash and takes the second part (i.e. 10/20)
            .split('/')[0] // Splits the string by the slash and takes the first part (i.e. 10)
        ) +
        delta // Adds the delta (which could be 1 or -1)
    );
    $('.unfavcom i').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('title', 'Remove from Favorite? - '+newCount+'/20');
    });
    $('.favcom i').each(function(){
        $(this).attr('title', 'Favorite Comment - '+newCount+'/20');
    });
}
```

Finally, update the `success` callbacks of your code, so they call the new function:

```
$(document).on('click', '.favcom', function() {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function() {
            updateCounts(1);
        }
    });
});

$(document).on('click', '.unfavcom', function() {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function() {
            updateCounts(-1);
        }
    });
});
```

If this is enough, you can save the `showlike`'s function and PHP script. If you really want to go to the server, then you can reuse the code I just gave you, but make the server return the number instead of having all the calculation I did, change the `delta` for the actual count and just update them all

**Update**

For your second question (limiting the flags to 20), it's easier to alert when it isn't possible to upvote more, which only requires you to check the database, like this:

```
<?php
// like.php
//...
if (isset($_POST['like'])) {
    // ...
    if (mysqli_num_rows($query) > 0) {
        // ...
    } else {
        $query = mysqli_query($conn,"select count(*) from `favcoms` where sessionid='".$_SESSION['id']."'") or die(mysqli_error());
        $row = $query->fetch_row();
        if($row[0] === 20){
            exit('Maximum upvotes reached');
        }
        mysqli_query($conn,"insert into `favcoms` (sessionid,fcom_id) values ('".$_SESSION['id']."', '$id')");
    }
}
```

And then you're able to use Javascript to let the user know, like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.favcom', function() {
    // ...
    $.ajax({
        // ...
        success: function(response) {
            if(response.length){
                //There's an error
                alert(response);
                return;
            }
            updateCounts(1);
        }
    });
});
```

Now, if you also want to disabled the action, you can toggle the buttons with something like this:

```
function updateCounts(delta){
    //...
    if(newCount === 20){
      // Limit reached, hide favcoms
      $('.favcom').hide();
    }else{
      // Not there yet, show favcoms
      $('.favcom').show();
    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Sir, I am not good at jquery and javascript. How to control the limit when 20 favorites are done, the empty star should either be disable for clicking, or on click it should give an popup alert that you have already favorited 20 comments. I think disable for click would be better option, and if he unfavorite a comment, empty star sign should again be active to be clicked... how to deal it.

Comment: I updated my answer to give you an idea on how to deal with that

Comment: i think there is some mistake from my side that i am not understanding due to lack of experience in jquery. its still not working. i sent you an email. can you plz check it out